# AnyLogic: Store different agents in rack system

Tags: java, rack, anylogic, agent

I am modelling an AS/RS in AnyLogic. The plastic containers handled are of different typologies. Basically, the difference in these typologies resides in the length of the container itself. The other measures are the same. As an example, let's imagine a container T1 with a length of 600 mm and a container T2 with a length of 300 mm. For the moment I created only one agent type for the container, which is created dynamically with the dimensions above mentioned.

The AS/RS cell length is 600 mm, thus it is possible to store one T1 and two T2 on a cell. For this reason, in AnyLogic I inserted 2 as the number of deep position for each cell. Nevertheless, I don't know how to manage this situation in terms of container storage/cell reservation/deep positions.

I hope that someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. This place works best for you if you ask very specific questions, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. Your question is not clear at all but quite broad. I suggest you read up here to learn how to ask great questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Treat us as very busy colleagues that are happy to help. The more effort you put into your question, the more likely you will get a good, fast reply :)

Answer (score 0):

thats where you will need to craft some code. For example one option coming to my mind - maybe you should dynamically replace one T1 with two T2 before you put it to cell. (Sounds stupid but it may work). 2nd option - whenever you put T1 to cell you have to make sure that second cell is free and on puting it you also reserve the second cell - use function reserve() for that (Sounds better then option 1 to me).

Comment: Thank you for the advices. I also tought using the function reserve. On the basis of the sintax of the function reserve() in AnyLogic:

void reserve(int row, int position, int level, boolean leftAisle) - Marks a given cell [row,position,level] as reserved. The cell must be free.

Does it work for the entire cell or there is a method to reserve a single deep position?